# Problems with assigning large vectors

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rinside

i have the following program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <RInside.h>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using namespace Rcpp;
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    RInside R;
    R.parseEvalQ("set.seed(1)"); Rcpp::RNGScope();
    const Function sample("sample");
    vector<int> vv = as<vector<int> >(sample(NumericVector::create(0,1,2,3), 1e6, true,NumericVector::create(.3,.3,.2,.2)));
    cout<<"1"<<endl<<std::flush;
    const vector<int> vv2 = as<vector<int> >(sample(NumericVector::create(0,1,2,3), 2e6, true,NumericVector::create(.3,.3,.2,.2)));
    cout<<"2"<<endl;
}
```

The output is

```
1
Segmentation fault
```

That means the C++ vector `vv2` cannot be initialized. Why can't vv2 be assigned?

With inline, here is what i got:

```
> body <- '
+ using namespace Rcpp;
+ using std::vector;
+ using std::cout;
+ using std::endl;
+      Rcpp::RNGScope();
+     const Function sample("sample");
+     vector<int> vv = as<vector<int> >(sample(NumericVector::create(0,1,2,3), 1e6, true,NumericVector::create(.3,.3,.2,.2)));
+     cout<<"1"<<endl<<std::flush;
+     const vector<int> vv2 = as<vector<int> >(sample(NumericVector::create(0,1,2,3), 2e6, true,NumericVector::create(.3,.3,.2,.2)));
+     cout<<"2"<<endl;
+     List vecs(2);
+     vecs[1]=vv;
+     vecs[1]=vv2;
+     return(vecs);
+     '
> require( inline )
Loading required package: inline
> require( Rcpp )
Loading required package: Rcpp
Loading required package: int64
> 
> signatures <- NULL
> fx <- cxxfunction( signatures, body, plugin = "Rcpp" )
> a <- fx()

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7f2b850eb013, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Primitive(".Call")(<pointer: 0x7f2b8627d2c0>)
 2: fx()

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do the same in R on your machine? 2 million elements is quite a lot.

Also, I almost never call back to R functions this way as it is inefficient.  If you want speed-up, reimplement `sample()` in C++ which can't be too hard.

Next, I'd also recommend simpler expression first tried via inline.

Lastly, and I'll sound like a broken record, try the rcpp-devel list.

Comment: That is not a vector, that is a single number. My question was if you can run the same `sample()` call with the same arguments in R, or do you run out of memory there too?

Comment: Why numeric(2e6) isn't a vector?

Comment: This works`> a=sample(0:3, 2e6, TRUE, c(.3, .3, .2, .2))
> length(a)
[1] 2000000`

Comment: Decompose the problem into several steps. Assign a 2e6 vector in Rcpp. Do a C++ function over it. Call a simple R function like `sum()` etc.  You have a complex statement there which may generate several temporary expressions.  And as I said, I don;t think calling R's `sample()` from C++ is a great idea.

Comment: Once i assign a 2e6 vector in Rcpp, even without returning any value, R will crash. The reason i call back to the R function is for convenience not speed. The code shown is only a small part of a bigger program.